# wxPython; populating a grid from values sent from a remote node one value at a time

Tags: wxpython

I have a remote node that holds values in 60 different registers. I need to populate a grid with the values on a button click. The only way I can get the values is one at a time. This works but it's messy. Each time I receive another value to add to the list, I get this error: "gridArray = np.array(table).reshape(15,4)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size (number of values in list) into shape (15,4)

```
def onGetValues(self, event):
    self.grid.ClearGrid() 
    for i in range(129,189):  #number of registers will never change
        #send me the data in each of these registers

#Then I build a list as the values are received:

def buildList(self, val):
    global myList
    myList.append(val)      # this gives me a list with one value, then two values, etc
    self.makeArray()  # go to the next step

#Then I turn the final list into an array:

def makeArray(self):
    global myList, gridArray
    gridArray = np.array(myList).reshape(15,4) # grid will never be bigger

#Then use the array to populate the grid:

def popGrid(self):
    global gridArray
    for row in gridArray:
        row_num = row[0]
        cells = row[0:4]
        for i in range(len(cells)):
            if cells [i] != None and cells[i] != "null":
                self.grid.SetCellValue(row_num-1, i, str(cells[i]))
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can I populate the grid from the last list I make and skip the array all together? Can this be condensed into one function?

Answer (score 0):

Since the length of the list will always be 60:

```
def buildList(self, val):
    global myList
    myList.append(val)
    if len(myList) == 60:
        self.makeArray()
```